# mapping of massives(react)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I have a list of items in the List of catalogue. Every item from `ListItem` should have dropdown `SubList`.

I'm working with reactjs (beginner) so don't know (yet) is there any option to make it beautiful.

**Question:** How is it possible to reach massive List and its data?

I definitely can reach my goal with pure html and css. But in future, it wouldn't be so nice to support such code.

So I'm trying to do it with map() but supposingly have a stupid mistake still can't find.

So my List of catalogue looks like [that one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbmD0.png)

and my code(for 1 table, just for example):

```
 const CatalogueListNames = [
       {
    catalogueNameType: 'appliance',
    catalogueName: 'Бытовая техника',
    ListItem: [
        {
            itemName: 'Крупногабаритная техника',
            itemPath: '/bulky_machines',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Встраиваемая техника',
            itemPath: '/built_in_appliances',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Уборка, уход за одеждой',
            itemPath: '/cleaning',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Климатическая техника',
            itemPath: '/climate',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Приготовление пищи',
            itemPath: '/cooking',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Приготовление кофе и чая',
            itemPath: '/tea_and_coffee',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Подготовка и обработка продуктов',
            itemPath: '/food_processing',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Уход за волосами и телом',
            itemPath: '/hygienics',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Техника для здоровья',
            itemPath: '/health',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            itemName: 'Сопутствующие товары и аксессуары',
            itemPath: '/accessories',
            SubList: [
                {
                    subItemPath: '/fridges',
                    subItemName: 'Холодильники',

                    subItemPath1: '/freezers',
                    subItemName1: 'Морозильники',

                    subItemPath2: '/washmachines',
                    subItemName2: 'Стиральные машины',

                    subItemPath3: '/driers',
                    subItemName3: 'Сушильные машины',

                    subItemPath4: '/stovehoods',
                    subItemName4: 'Вытяжки',

                    subItemPath5: '/cookers',
                    subItemName5: 'Кухонные плиты',

                    subItemPath6: '/dishwashers',
                    subItemName6: 'Посудомоечные машины',

                    subItemPath7: '/wineracks',
                    subItemName7: 'Винные шкафы',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
];
```

and here

```
const Catalogue = () => {
  return (
    <div className={"CatalogueFull"}>
      {CatalogueListNames.map((itemData, index) => {
        return (
          <div className={"CatalogueItem"}>
            <CatalogueName
              key={`${itemData.catalogueNameType}` + { index }}
              type={itemData.catalogueNameType}
            >
              {itemData.catalogueName}
            </CatalogueName>
            {itemData.ListItem.map((ListItem, index) => {
              return (
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <CatalogueItemsList
                      key={index}
                      itemName={ListItem.itemName}
                      itemPath={ListItem.itemPath}
                    />
                    {ListItem.Sublist.map((SubList, index) => {
                      return (
                        <CatalogueItemsListSubList
                          key={index}
                          subItemPath={SubList.subItemPath}
                          subItemName={SubList.subItemName}
                          subItemPath1={SubList.subItemPath1}
                          subItemName1={SubList.subItemName1}
                          subItemPath2={SubList.subItemPath2}
                          subItemName2={SubList.subItemName2}
                          subItemPath3={SubList.subItemPath3}
                          subItemName3={SubList.subItemName3}
                          subItemPath4={SubList.subItemPath4}
                          subItemName4={SubList.subItemName4}
                          subItemPath5={SubList.subItemPath5}
                          subItemName5={SubList.subItemName5}
                          subItemPath6={SubList.subItemPath6}
                          subItemName6={SubList.subItemName6}
                          subItemPath7={SubList.subItemPath7}
                          subItemName7={SubList.subItemName7}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div> /*cataloguefull*/
  );
}; /*catalogue*/
```

I know something wrong is going with massive CatalogueListNames and List is inside. Also I'm not sure about second map() (is it even legit to use 2 map()'s in one row?) 1st map() is working. Second is not.

Comment: 2 maps is fine. Create sub arrays, and store name/path in those. Absolutely avoid what you're doing. It's an eye sore, and will be a pain to debug/add new items.

Comment: @FrankerZ thanks for reply! I've tried to follow your advice and that what I've got for now. Did i understand you right?

And still I cannot reach SubList via 3rd map() (though the 1st and the 2nd are working - yay!). It's undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon @FrankerZ's comment, you might want something like this.

I didn't feel like rewriting all of the items by hand, so the example is not quite as massive, but the idea is the same.

As an added bonus, this snippet automatically supports an infinite number of `children` within items and renders them as nested `<ul>`s, but you can naturally change how things get rendered.

```js
const items = [
  {
    itemName: "Крупногабаритная техника",
    itemPath: "/bulky_machines",
    children: [
      {
        itemPath: "/fridges",
        itemName: "Холодильники"
      },
      {
        itemPath: "/freezers",
        itemName: "Морозильники"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    itemName: "Встраиваемая техника",
    itemPath: "/built_in_appliances",
    children: [
      {
        itemPath: "/fridges",
        itemName: "Холодильники"
      },
      {
        itemPath: "/washmachines",
        itemName: "Стиральные машины"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Item = ({ item, parent }) => (
  <li>
    {item.itemName} (parent={parent ? parent.itemName : "none"})
    {item.children && item.children.length ? (
      <ul>
        {item.children.map((child, index) => (
          <Item item={child} parent={item} key={index} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    ) : null}
  </li>
);

const App = () => (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <Item item={item} parent={null} key={index} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main id="root" />
```

Comment: wow, AKX! It so works! Is it "recursion" idea? Doubt if I even could to guess that approach! Thank you so much!